# Symfony2 what to do when deploying manually? 

Tags: symfony

Since i can't find any useful information on Symfony2 website i'm asking here. What should be done when **manually deploying a Symfony2 project**? As far i understand:

- Edit `app/config/paramenters.ini` to meet server paramenters
- Update vendors to the latest version: `php bin/vendors update`
- Install database with `php app/console doctrine:database:create` then tables with `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` and eventually load fixtures: `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load`
- Dump and install assets/assetics: `php app/console assets:install --symlink web` as long as `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`
- Symlink `index.php` to `web/app.php`, assuming that all files from Symfony2 distribution are in the root of the web server
- Remove `web/app_dev.php` (is this really necessary?)
- should `app/config/paramenters.ini` left untouched? What about security concerns?

Am i right? Thanks for helping. I think that Symfony2 documentation should cover this too.

**EDIT**: virtual host example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/Symfony2/web"
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    <Directory "C:/www/Symfony2/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only two things I wouldn't do is:

> Symlink index.php to web/app.php, assuming that all files from
>   Symfony2 distribution are in the root of the web server
>
> Remove web/app_dev.php (is this really necessary?)

The thing with the symlink might be ok, but I prefer to link the webroot directory with the web directory of symfony2.

Second thing is, you don't have to remove app_dev.php, because it can only be run from localhost (it checks the IP). So no need to remove it, and I personally sometimes want to see debug info on the webpage (maybe not best way), and than I just add my own IP to app_dev (and remove it afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is all. And also you don't need `web/app_dev.php` in prod environment.

Moreover, `web` folder should be document root and run `app.php`

Comment: What about `app/config/paramenters.ini`? And i'm right about symliking `app.php`?

Comment: @Gremo yeah, totally. Make 'web' folder DocumentRoot and point to `app.php` or maybe rename it to index.php

On the other hand, just fill in `parameters.ini` respectively. It is only about database, mailer and such parameters

Comment: Ok i was so wrong. `web` folder should be document root then! Good to know! Update your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `DirectoryIndex app.php` inside `<Directory></Directory>`